# questions on pandas group by functionality?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, concatenation

I have the following data set:

```
productid att
12        block10
12        block20
12        clean
12        screw
12        nail
13        hard
13        cover
14        round
14        narrow
14        black
15        block4
```

I wanted to group the dataframe according to the product id and get the following result:

```
productid att
12        block10 block20 clean screw nail
13        hard cover
14        round narrow black
15        block4
```

I can use pandas.groupby('productid') to group my data but I am not sure how to write all the data for a specific productid to a single row separated by a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` on 'productid' and then `apply` a join:

```
In [6]:
df.groupby('productid')['att'].apply(' '.join)

Out[6]:
productid
12    block10 block20 clean screw nail
13                          hard cover
14                  round narrow black
15                              block4
Name: att, dtype: object
```